# Simulate from a distribution using Metropolis-Hastings and Rejection Sampling?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, sampling

We have covered the basics behind rejection sampling as well as Metropolis-Hastings from class, but I am not sure how to use the two in conjunction to solve the following problem:

Given $\pi(x) = \frac{1}{M}f(x)$, where $M = \int f(x)dx$, where we know $f(x)$ but do not know $M$, how can we efficiently simulate samples from $\pi(x)$?

We are supposed to use a combination of rejection sampling and Metropolis Hastings but I am not quite sure how to begin.

Comment: What does $Z$ represent here? When I get to my office, I have already coded up the metroplis hastings method. As far as I know MH is a class of acceptance rejection sampling? So I am confused by your last question.

Comment: Sorry was a typo. Meant M instead. Yes MH is a type of acceptance rejection but I believe we are allowed to use other forms of sampling along with MH (as long as they too fall in the class of acceptance rejection).

Comment: You don't need to compute the normalisation because you deal with ratios of distributions(well for the symmetric case at least) .